# Is this IR LED driver circuit with a transistor OK?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, infrared

I am making a custom IR array board with a custom Arduino (only ATMEGA328 and necessary components.) So please tell me will this be fine or if I need to make some changes.

IR LED = 940nm, continuous forward current is 100mA, the forward voltage is 1.4.
         Current forward = 20mA with 1.2 forward voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fie9Me.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please do suggest will it work with IRFz44N?

So instead of if I use any NPN transistor with this parallel circuit, it will work fine, right? So please let me know if this is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will it work with IRFz44N

No, you are driving this MOSFET with a 5V Vgs, thus you need a MOSFET that has RdsON specified at 5V Vgs, otherwise it may work, or maybe not. For IRFZ44 it is only specified at 10V. You can use IR**L**Z44 for example, here's its spec:

[image]

Your schematic is OK but:

The LEDs are going to draw some pretty high pulsed current, so I'd add a capacitor between the FET's source and the LED's positive supply. Either a low-ESR electrolytic, or a 10µF ceramic.

If you're powering the arduino from a 5V supply then check that it has enough current capability for the LEDs. If you use a higher voltage supply (like 12V) then the internal regulator on the arduino may overheat and shutdown if you draw such high current from it. Remember dissipation in a linear regulator is (Vin-Vout)*I. So you need to check and make sure it'll be OK.

Comment: Arduino can give max Current output from GPIO up to max 900mA so there's no issue there. I can use an NPN transistor instead of this MOSFET. And Sir  Capacitor between FET and LED power Supply means? LED power supply (5V and GND of MOSFET?) or else?

Comment: Yes you can use NPN if it can take the current. Decoupling cap between GND and +5V.

Comment: @El_Dorado Can you point me to *anything* that suggests a GPIO on an Arduino (any of them) can support a max of 900 mA? Are you reading the "Absolute Maximum Specifications?"

Comment: @jonk I think he refers to the onboard regulator, for which a 900mA rating is highly suspicious given the lack of a heat sink, so I mentioned in the answer that he should check the dissipation... OP will learn eventually XD

Comment: It was My mistake Sorry. I am gonna use only ATMEGA328P only not the whole Arduino.  And if I use any NPN transistor with this parallel IR ckt it will work, right? Asking for confirmation Sir.

Comment: That mosfet has a threshold of 2 to 4 volts. It doesnt have a RdsON listed for lower values but that doesnt mean it won't work.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, Sir. After creating the ckt I will post here if there's an issue or if it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, at 500 mA or less of power draw for your leds through the IRFz44N, it would be fine. It has a Vgs Threshold of 2V min and 4V max, and the Vgs to Id graph shows it will pass up to 20 Amps at 5V Vgs.

Comment: So IRFz44N will be good, right? No additional things required just this ckt. And this ckt is good as it is. Just to be sure.

Comment: Based on the information you provide, yes. The mosfet you use isnt ideal or typically used for something like this but should work because its low current.

Comment: Ok, Sir, I will make this circuit and try if there will be any problem I will post here.
Sir, if the voltage from atmega328p is isn't fully 5V then also there will no issues, right? just for confirmation.

Comment: The GPIO voltage should be close to the ATMEGA's VCC or VIN voltage. Since this is a Mosfet, there should be little change in the GPIO output voltage as there is no large load on the GPIO. But to answer your question, the circuit can have issue if the GPIO voltage is between 2 to 4 volts or less.

Comment: Its voltage would be I think between 4 to 5 so it will work I guess. I have created the same ws2812 SMD LED array with 8 leds. And supplied it with 5V 1A power supply so just need guidance that should I have to use this MOSFET there also for driving LED's?

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered the basic question. This answer is just to show a more conventional schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9zU6p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's schematic redrawn in conventional manner.*

For ease of reading and showing the intent of the schema normal practice is to enable reading from left to right with higher voltages at the top and lower voltages at the bottom. This allows easier analysis of current flow, etc.

With this layout and the use of ground symbols it is immediately clear that M1 is acting as a negative rail switch on the load.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the MOSFET with "any NPN transistor" will not work. However, it should be fairly easy to make the system work- as long as the unstated requirements are not too demanding.

First, your GPIO will not put out much current. See  [the data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf)
 p 339. The data sheet indicates that a pin can put out about 20 mA with an output voltage of 4.4 volts, and the absolute maximum rating (which you should NEVER use as an operating point) is 40 mA (with an unknown voltage).

Subtracting about 0.8 volts for the base-emitter diode drop, this give 3.6 volts across the resistor, and this in turn requires a resistance of 90 ohms. Your 1k will limit the base current to about 4 mA.

You want the transistor to act as a switch, with very low Vce, and this is called saturation. What you don't realize is that when a transistor is in saturation its gain is very low - 10 is the usual rule of thumb. This in turn says that your maximum LED current will be on the order of 40 mA.

You have not identified your LEDs, nor have you identified the current levels you want. Assuming (just as a starting point) that D1/D7/D4 are red LEDs with a forward drop at desired current of 1.4 volts, the LEDs will drop about 4.2 volts, leaving (assuming zero volts across the transistor) of about 0.8 volts across a 10 ohm resistor, for an LED current of 80 mA. Assuming all 3 branches have the same current, this implies a total current of 240 mA, which is comfortably less than 40 mA, and implies a base current on the order of 24 mA.

If this analysis corresponds to your requirements, you should be OK. You will need to get transistor bigger than a small-signal device, with a maximum collector current in the vicinity of 800 mA to 1 A or higher. You will need to examine data sheets to choose the proper transistor.

Comment: It was solved at that time only. But thank you for your response, Sir. I calculated the LED's power requirement and adjusted the resistors according to the transistor. I worked fine. At that time I had started learning little things and now I understand the effect of calculation and features of some components. Still, a lot to learn and grow.